# A star: finding nearest of multiple goals

Tags: a-star

I am working on project where i need to find a path to the nearest (of many) goal node in 2D grid (8 connections in any node: N,S,W,E,NW,NE,SW,SE). There can be walls blocking path on the way. There is no problem when it comes to find path to one goal node, but how could i find in reasonable time which goal is nearest? I don't think running A* for every goal node and getting length of every path found to compare is reasonable way, how else can it be done?

Is A* somehow capable of finding path to nearest node, or the nearest goal must be found other way and then passed to A* as only goal?

[image]

Legend:

White - walkable

Grey - walls

Blue - myself

Green - goals

Red - enemy (i am planing to keep distance from enemy at X SQM)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just set `EstimatedDistanceToEnd` (aka. `h(x)`) to the minimum estimate over all end-nodes.  Then just stop the search when you hit an end-node.

Answer (score 1):

A* is for informed searches where we have some data other than just goal state... According to your question it seems like there is no relevant data and we just know what our goal state is. If that is the case then you can simply apply [BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search).